# How can I turn my Rails app into a plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am currently developing a cms and want to reuse the functionality in other projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Rails Engines.

Its awesome to share code between your applications. you can sort of make your application into a plugin itself

Try this railscast as well, Ryan bates explains it nicely

http://railscasts.com/episodes/149-rails-engines

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked about building a CMS in Rails I suggest you reading these links below

[The Ruby on Rails CMS Dilemma](http://aaronlongwell.com/2009/06/the-ruby-on-rails-cms-dilemma.html)